# Using pre-made elements in html tags

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to understand if using pre-made elements withn an HTML tag consider to be valid. I have start to use it all over my HTML to make my code become more generic and less breakable. However I am unaware if this is valid and supported by all browsers.

For example , I am doing something like that :

```
<a class="item-class" href="...' itemname="something">
```

now assume I am doing an jquery onclick event for all item-class I can do

```
$(this).attr("itemname")
```

kind of passing parameters to jquery events.

Comment: I more elegant solution would be to use HTML5 data tags.

Comment: You can assign any attribute you like without the page breaking, but it's not valid HTML. If you use a newer doctype data attributes are valid, like `data-itemname="something"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be using for this sort of meta data, as per the HTML5 spec is the [data-* attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). It works basically the same, it's just you use `data-itemname="itemname" instead.

The is also a proper [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for editing/retrieving these values:

```
<a class="item-class" href="...' data-itemname="something">
$(this).data("itemname")
```

Comment: thanks ! Any problem using the HTML5 data- in older browsers ?

Comment: No more of a problem then using the original attributes you were using!

Answer (score 0):

`itemanem` is not a valid attribute you can use HTML5 `data-*` attribute and jQuery `data()` method instead:

```
<a class="item-class" href="...' data-name="something">
```

```
$(this).data("name")
```

However, if you want to read the non-standard attributes you can use `getAttribute` method:

```
var itemName = $(this)[0].getAttribute("itemname")
```